# Need help understanding WCF Security Architecture

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

So I've been banging my head against the wall for the past couple days trying to understand how WCF's security architecture worked. I have a goal in mind and I'm not sure that I'm going in the right direction.

**The System**

We use a combination of Active Directory and databases to manage our authentication and authorization. Client applications typically use their Windows credentials to authenticate and the applications checks against database tables to see if those users are allowed to authenticate and then if they are authorized to use the resources they are requesting. The current setup has each client directly communicating with the database to do these checks.

**The Goal**

We want to use a Security Token Service to authenticate the client and provide "high level" authorizations for top level resources. The services that provide data or perform actions would operate if the supplied SecurityToken was valid. Additionally, the token, if it did not contain a particular right, would query the token service to see if the user did have rights that were not loaded when the token was initially created. (We have over 300 rights in our database, and that could lead to rather hefty tokens for users with many rights)

**What I Don't Understand**

1) I understand the token creation process, but I'm a little lost on how the client gets, stores and sends the token to the services it intends to use. Does each "worker" service require a unique token (i.e. call to CalculatorService requires one version of the token and the SaveResultService require a new token to be generated?) Can I manually request, save and send tokens?

2) On the "worker" service side, what is the process by which the token is verified? Does my "worker" service have to contact the Token Service for verification of the token? Or does it just read the token and assume, if it is properly signed, that the token is genuine and operate from that perspective?

3) Is it possible to encrypt my tokens manually and store them on the client side for use while they are valid (thus avoiding authentication attempts on every service call) and so that a web client can save the token between page loads and reuse it on successive calls?

Thanks for helping with my lack of understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through the samples for Windows Identity foundation - It providers the classes and implementations required to wrap claims that you can use or query for auth and authz.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517291.aspx

What you are looking for is a durable token cache. - Tokens have lifetimes and usually require renewal and WIF does the renewal under the hood for most scenarios.

You can manually request and attach tokens and pool the proxies using WIF.